# Probability of two sine signals producing peaks at the same time

Tags: probability, signal-processing, density-function

What is the probability of two sine signals producing peaks at the same time?

Let us assume that the two are independent and have the same frequency, but with different amplitudes. A peak is sure to occur for one of the phase angles in $0$ to $\pi$.

Can this be extended to 3 signals? How to find the probability density function of the sines?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: This sounds a lot like homework. Is there something in particular you are having trouble formulating or understanding?

Comment: I only have a vague idea of this question a friend had asked me. It isn't a homework problem. The initial discussion was this - what are the chances that two independent sine wave generators will generate the exact same starting phase angle (leading to simultaneous peaks) or even opposite phases (leading to destructive interference)?

Comment: In order to consider this question I think you would have to consider the signal to noise ratio of the process, or have some knowledge of the noise distribution ( probably additive white Gaussian to make things simpler).I'm just assuming there is noise or this question wouldn't make sense. So you need to better define the problem I think.

Comment: There is no noise needed. Just imagine two sine wave generators (like those found in electronics labs). Either of them can be started at any moment within an interval of half the time period, with frequency of the waves fixed. What is the probability of the two sine waves having peaks at the same time? Assume what extra you need, but mention assumptions explicitly.

Comment: If we assume all moments within half the time period have equal chances for being the moment when sine wave starts, then we have uniform probability. In terms of phase angle, the starting phase angle would lie in $[0, \pi)$

Answer (score 2):

If you mean at the same time exactly, the probibility is $0$. If you mean within a certain range, then the probability can be calculated using the probability density function.

Comment: The starting phase angle of the two independent sine wave generators will lie in $[0,2 \pi)$. If the probability of any phase to be the starting phase is uniform, how to find the probability of two of them having same starting phase (leading to simultaneous peaks)? Thank you.

Comment: I believe he is saying that you have to integrate the joint PDF over some finite region in order to get a non-zero probability.